# Game Center Achievement completion banner not showing up on iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, game-center

After completing Game Center achievement, achievement complete banner is not showing up on iOS7. GKAchievement.showsCompletionBanner is already set to YES. It works perfectly fine in iOS6 and iOS5. Anyone have any ideas to make this work? Thx.

This is the property in GKAchievement class I'm refering to.

```
@property(assign, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY) BOOL showsCompletionBanner __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_8,__IPHONE_5_0);             // A banner will be momentarily displayed after reporting a completed achievement
```

Answer (score 18):

It seems to be broken in iOS 7. Below is a fix that I use. You just need some condition to fill in the **Title** and **Message**. Hope this helps.

```
[GKNotificationBanner showBannerWithTitle:@"Achievement" message:@"Completed!" completionHandler:^{}];
```

Comment: I already know about this but you still need to load the "achievement earned description" from itunesconnect, that's something I was trying to avoid

Comment: We'll just have to wait until Apple fixes it. There are a lot of stuff broken in iOS 7 SDK. Some are also incomplete. Hopefully they'll have some fix for this soon. As far as the doc is concerned atm, this is not deprecated.

Comment: Is this broken for sure, or one of those things that sometimes work, sometimes don't on the sandbox environment? I ask, because I don't want to end up showing two banners to the user! Also, what about iOS 7.1?

Comment: BTW, this post in Unity forums seems to suggest that it's a sandbox-only issue... http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/201498-IOS7-and-Game-Center-Achievements-no-banners-displayed